# Google Cloud Cpp Could not Found Internal .h Files

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, cmake

This is the sample CPP file which includes a GCP header file:

```
#include <google/cloud/storage/client.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "here i am!" << std::endl;
}
```

And this is the CMake file:

```
add_subdirectory(gcp/super)
include_directories(gcp)
set(MYSRC mycode.cc)
add_executable(mycode ${MYSRC})
target_link_libraries(mycode storage_client)
```

But it raises errors:

```
In file included from /home/morteza/google-cloud-cpp-0.20.0/mycode.cc:1:
/home/morteza/google-cloud-cpp-0.20.0/gcp/google/cloud/storage/client.h:18:10: fatal error: google/cloud/internal/disjunction.h: No such file or directory
   18 | #include "google/cloud/internal/disjunction.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mycode.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/mycode.dir/mycode.cc.o] Error 1
```

As you see this is completely the internal part of the GCP (`client.h` includes `disjunction.h`).

Comment: You have not included the path to the SDK include files. Where did you install them? Try `find / -type f -name disjunction.h`.

Comment: I've run it but nothing exists. But it's completely internal of the Google-Cloud-Cpp.

Comment: The SDK still needs to be installed. Internal just means you do not reference the file directly in your code. There is no magic, if the file is not on your system in a known location, the compiler cannot find it.

Comment: @JohnHanley so, do you have any idea about what SDK I have to install?

Comment: I don't see `disjunction.h` in the directory I'd expect it to be on Github [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/tree/master/google/cloud/storage/internal). Is it a generated file, or located elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know what SDK you are using. Read the documentation on how to download, install setup set up. Details like this should be in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you need to also add the following into your environment:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp-common